# Starlab (written in QT) hangs when trying to run

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++

I try to compile and run [starlab](https://github.com/opengp/starlab) (a 3D geometry processing environment written in Qt 5). I can successfully compile it in Qt Creator with a visual studio compiler, but when I try to run it afterwards, it always hangs (and gives no error).

I also checked if I could run one of the examples that is provided with Qt Creator, but they have the same problem. So, I guess there is something wrong with my Qt installation or with the compiler I use? Maybe there is some way to check what is going wrong when running the application?

My setup: Windows 10 x64 with an Intel x64 processor, Qt 5.5, compiler: win32-msvc2013 x64 (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (amd64))

I already tried some other compilers and Qt versions, like: Qt 5.2.1, win32-msvc2015, win32-msvc2012. All have the same problem.

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? There have been several recent questions where Avast is causing this or similar problems.

Comment: I didn't think this would work, but surprisingly it did. Thank you so much!